How to prevent downloading the desktop component code in Next.js when using dynamic imports based on user-agent?
I'm trying to create a layout in Next.js where the component rendered depends on the device (mobile or desktop). I want to prevent the desktop layout's source code from being downloaded to the browser if the user is on a mobile device. Here's what I have:


"use server";

import React, {ReactNode, ComponentType} from "react";

import {parseUserAgent} from "@repo/helpers";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import {headers} from "next/headers";

interface Props {
  CommonWrapper?: ComponentType<{children: ReactNode}>;
  MobileComponent: () => Promise<{default: React.ComponentType<any>}>;
  DesktopComponent: () => Promise<{default: React.ComponentType<any>}>;
}

const withResponsiveLayout = async ({
  CommonWrapper,
  MobileComponent,
  DesktopComponent,
}: Props) => {
  const header = new Headers(headers());
  const parsedUserAgent = parseUserAgent(header);
  let isMobile = parsedUserAgent?.device.is("mobile");

  const Wrapper = CommonWrapper ?? React.Fragment;
  const Component = isMobile
    ? dynamic(MobileComponent)
    : dynamic(DesktopComponent);

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Component />
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

export default withResponsiveLayout;



// example

'use server'

async function Page() {
  const data = await getSomeData();

  return await withResponsiveLayout({
    CommonWrapper: ({children}: PropsWithChildren) => (
      <MandatoryAuthWrapper>
        <CommonProvier initialData={data}>{children}</CommonProvier>
      </MandatoryAuthWrapper>
    ),
    DesktopComponent: () => import("./Main"),
    MobileComponent: () => import("./MobMain"),
  });
}



I'm trying to render either a mobile or desktop layout based on the user-agent, and I want to ensure that the desktop layout never gets downloaded by the browser if the user is on a mobile device. I don't want to make the layout responsive but rather load an entirely different layout based on the device.
Am I doing something wrong in my approach? How can I ensure the desktop component is excluded from the client-side bundle entirely when the user is on a mobile device?

After going through the doc of dynamic, it simply delays and does not hold the script from loading. Any solution to this?

Just to mark this answered,
Instead of using the hook to handle the switching of UI i simply the condition directly inside the page.ts


async function Page() {
  const data = await getSomeData();
  
  const isMobile = customFunctionToPrseUserAgent()
  
  if (isMobile) return <>UI FOR MOBILE</>
  
  return NORMAL UI
}



